# object calling a method confusion

Tags: java, generics

Why is the class GenericMethodDemo invoking the method print? Shouldn't an object be created first, and then have an object invoke a method? Thank you so very much.

```
public class GenericMethodDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Integer[] integers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
         String[] strings = {"London", "Paris", "New York", "Austin"};

         GenericMethodDemo.<Integer>print(integers);
         GenericMethodDemo.<String>print(strings);
    }

    public static <E> void print(E[] list)
    {
         for (int i = 0; i<list.length;i++)
         {
             System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Both `main` and `print` are static - no instances of `GenericMethodDemo` are required.

Comment: Thank you! You are right! I should really grind myself in differentiating static and non-static (instances) better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`print` is a static method, so to call it you specify the name of the class that contains that method. You don't need an object of the `GenericMethodDemo` class in order to call `print`.

Comment: Thank you so very much. That makes sense now. thank you